# Непредвиденные лексемы перед ; Отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, c++11

Создаю объект Packman* p = new Packman() в классе Game. Но выдает в этом месте 3 ошибки: 
1) Непредвиденные лексемы перед ; 
2) Отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
3) Синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "*"

```
Game.cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "Packman.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "Ghost.h"
#include "Pellet.h"
#include<memory>

class Pacman;
class Game
{
public:
Game();

void start();
void startLoop();
void loadField();
void printDownload();

char getField(int y, int x);
void eatPellet(int y, int x, char c);


private:
Packman* p = new Packman();
char field_[FIELD_HEIGHT][FIELD_WIDTH];
};


main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"Game.h"

int main()
{
Game* game = new Game();
game->start();
return 0;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: `Pacman` или `Packman`? Кроме этого код корректный, см. в Packman.h

Comment: @asianirish очень глупая ошибка получилась. Спасибо, что указали на нее. Работает =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то непонятно, где ваш `Game.h`...

Но пока - тут

```
Packman* p = new Packman();
```

компилятор должен знать, что такое `Packman()`, т.е. иметь *полное объявление* класса `Packman`. А его как раз и нет...

Если вы понадеялись на наличие строки

```
class Pacman;
```

то это неполное объявление (пока вы не привели код в `"Packman.h"` - остается предполагать, что там ничего нет, файл пустой, и ограничиваться тем, что есть... Какой вопрос - такой и ответ :)).

И это неполное объявление - совсем не класса `Packman`, а `Pacman`.

Но даже если бы там было указано верное имя - то использовать

```
= new Packman();
```

вы все равно не имеете права - без полного объявления класса.